# Filter-Out Duplicate Table Entries

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I want to read in T1 and write it out as T2 (note both are .csv).
T1 contains duplicate rows; I don't want to write duplicates in T2.

T1

```
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| Type | Year | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| a    |    8 | x       | y       | z       |
| b    |   10 | q       | r       | s       |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

T2

```
+------+------+---------+-------+
| Type | Year | Value # | Value |
+------+------+---------+-------+
| a    | 8    | 1       | x     |
| a    | 8    | 2       | y     |
| a    | 8    | 3       | z     |
| b    | 10   | 1       | q     |
| ...  | ...  | ...     | ...   |
+------+------+---------+-------+
```

Currently, I have this excruciatingly slow code to filter out duplicates:

```
no_dupes = []

for row in reader:
    type = row[0]
    year = row[1]
    index = type,age
    values_list = row[2:]

    if index not in no_dupes:
        for i,j in enumerate(values_list):
            line = [type, year, str(i+1), str(j)]
            writer.writerow(line) #using csv module
            no_dupes.append(index)
```

I cannot exagerate how slow this code is when T1 gets large.

Is there a faster way to filter out duplicates from T1 as I write to T2?

Comment: At a minimum, you are adding `index` to the `no_dupes` list every time through the loop. So: (1) change `no_dupes` to a `set` and (2) add `index` to `no-dupes` only once per loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
no_dupes = set()

for row in reader:
    type, year = row[0], row[1]
    values_list = row[2:]

    for index, value in enumerate(values_list, start=1):
        line = (type, year, index, value)
        no_dupes.add(line)

for t in no_dupes:
    writer.writerow(t)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is substantially faster.

Answer (score 0):

If possible convert reader to a set and iterate over the set instead, then there is no possibility of dups

Comment: I can't do this using csv.reader(); each row in reader is a list.